# should.kind_of?(model) error with expect syntax in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I had this:

```
builder.class.should.kind_of?(MyCustomFormBuilder)
```

which I changed to

```
expect(builder.class).to be kind_of?(MyCustomFormBuilder)
```

but I get

```
   expected #<FalseClass:0> => false
        got #<Class:25336780> => MyCustomFormBuilder
```

How can I do this comparison with `expect`?

Answer (score 0):

Switching from

```
builder.class.should.kind_of?(MyCustomFormBuilder)
```

to this format

```
expect(builder).to be_kind_of(MyCustomFormBuilder)
```

worked.

Note:

- just `builder`, not `builder.class`
- `be_kind_of`, not `kind_of?`